# You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected in http get in angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

i am trying to send OTP after validating the login credentials.
login creds get validated and JWT token gets generated.
i have tested the API on postman and it works(i.e. i recieve email with OTP) but problem resides on the FE side.
the only thing is i dont recieve email.

---

//service starts HERE

```
user_login(username: string, password: string) {
var data = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password + 
"&grant_type=password";
var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www- 
urlencoded', 'No-Auth': 'True' });

return this.http.post<any>(this.rootUrl + '/token', data, { headers: 
reqHeader })
  .pipe(map(data => {
    // console.log(data, 'in service');
    // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
    if (data && data.access_token) {
      console.log("data & token");
      // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user 
      logged in between page refreshes
      localStorage.setItem('temp', data.access_token);
    }
    return data;
  }));
}

 send_otp(username: string): Observable<any> {
 console.log('send_otp: ' + username);
 let url = this.rootUrl + '/api/account/SendOTP?email=' + username;
 console.log(url);
 return this.http.get(url)
  .pipe(
    map(data => {
      return data;
    }),
    catchError(x => {

   console.log(x);
      return throwError(x);
    }));
   }
```

---

```
  // .ts code here
  if (event == "login") {
  // console.log('hi');
  this.authenticationService.user_login(this.f.username.value, 
  this.f.password.value)
    .pipe(first())
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data, 'in ts');


  this.authenticationService.send_otp(this.f.username.value).subscribe(x => 
  {
          console.log("otp sent");
        });

      },
      error => {
        this.isLoginError = true;
        this.loading = false;
      });
   }
```

expected : send OTP to the designated email.

**Edit:**

```
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

constructor(private router: Router) { }

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

if (req.headers.get('No-Auth') == "True")
return next.handle(req.clone());

if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser') != null ) {
const clonedreq = req.clone({
headers: req.headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('currentUser'))
});
return next.handle(clonedreq)
.pipe(tap(
succ => { },
err => {
//if (err.status === 401)
//this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
}
));
}
else {
this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
}
}
}
```

Comment: Are there any exceptions in the developer console in the browser? and also have you set a break point at the server side method /api/account/SendOTP?email=' + username to see what is happening?

Comment: Could you please show your `http interceptor`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting your token from server you saved this in local storage with key `temp`

```
localStorage.setItem('temp', data.access_token);
```

But if you look closely in `AuthInterceptor` you'll find that you only handle your http request for below conditions only

```
if (req.headers.get('No-Auth') == "True"){
  ....
}

if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser') != null ) {
  ....
}
```

But not for `temp` key in local storage.

And that's why you'd get this error

> You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected

So to get rid from this error, you'll need to modify second condition to check whether access token in `temp` key is exist or not like

```
if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser') != null ||  localStorage.getItem('temp') != null) {
 ....
}
```

Hope this will help you.